# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'add_patch'

Tags: python, image, deep-learning, data-science

I am working in grad-cam (vgg16) code I had the heatmap, I want to localize the important areas in the original image by a bounding box so I added some lines to the code but I didn't get result, and I finished up with errors, I'm new to python and deep learning so I don't know how to fix it, can anyone help me please it is for my project of master and I don't have much time.https://github.com/insikk/Grad-CAM-tensorflow/blob/master/gradCAM_tensorflow_VGG16_demo.ipynb

```
for b in props:
    bbox = b.bbox
    xs = bbox[1]
    ys = bbox[0]
    w = bbox[3] - bbox[1]
    h = bbox[2] - bbox[0]

    rect = patches.Rectangle((xs, ys), w, h, linewidth=2, edgecolor='r',facecolor='none') 
    img_box= img.add_patch(rect)


img_box = fig.add_subplot(112)
imgplot = plt.imshow(img_box)
ax.set_title('bounding box')
```